# Error: Wrapper cannot find servlet class VendorRegistration or a class it depends on

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm a newb whose also been searching for a solution to the same problem. I've followed the steps that the Elite Gentleman and Bozho outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701118/how-to-rectify-the-following-error-while-using-servlet). So first of all, thanks a lot guys. But I still seem to have the same problem. Now as per my understanding and implementation, my situation is as follows:

My servlet class VendorRegistration is available in the folder: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\VendorReg\WEB-INF\classes

My web.xml is present at: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\VendorReg\WEB-INF\

However, I still seem to be getting the error:

****HTTP Status 500 -
type Exception report message description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request. exception javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class VendorRegistration or a class it depends on****

I have also appended my web.xml file below for your consideration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5">

  <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
  <description>
     Welcome to Tomcat
  </description>
  <servlet>

    <servlet-name>VendorRegistration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>VendorRegistration</servlet-class>

  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>VendorRegistration</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/VendorRegistration</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

I am trying to access the servlet through the URL: http://localhost:8080/VendorReg/VendorRegistration. What am I missing ? I had compiled the .class file sometime before I installed Apache. And hence directly copied pasted the class file in the folder. Could that be a problem ?

Comment: This error also occurs when you have disabled automatic building of your projects in eclipse. so, there is no class file for all the java files/servlets that you have created. Hence, the error. To fix - `Select your project > Eclipse > Project > Build Project`. Run your code again.

Answer (score 5):

The servlet or one of its dependencies is missing in the classpath.

First of all, always put Java classes in a package, also servlets. Packageless classes are invisible to classes in a normal package. For servlets, this works in specific environments only. You don't want to be dependent on that.

```
package com.example;

public class VendorRegistration extends HttpServlet {
    // ...
}
```

With this package, the compiled `.class` file must end up in `/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/VendorRegistration.class`. Don't forget to alter the associated `<servlet-class>` entry in `web.xml` accordingly.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>VendorRegistration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.VendorRegistration</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

If that doesn't help, then you should put the classes or JAR files containing the (in)direct classes which are specified in any of the servlet's `import` statements also in `/WEB-INF/classes` (for `.class` files) or `/WEB-INF/lib` (for JAR files). The root cause in the exception stacktrace should tell which class exactly it is. Just read the stacktrace.

#### See also:

- [Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains a Hello World and several useful links

Comment: This explains everything. Reason : wrong paths mapped to servlets in web.xml file

Answer (score 2):

From tomcat 6.0 onwards, there is change in `<url-pattern>`

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>VendorRegistration</servlet-name>
<servlet-name>VendorRegistration</servlet-name>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>VendorRegistration</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/servlets/servlet/VendorRegistration</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It worked in my case!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem started when I made a copy/paste of HelloWorld.java class example from another project. Finally I solved it out by simply creating a new package, then a new HelloWorld.java from scratch and copy just the code for the `doGet()` method.

Then I restarted the server and ran http://localhost:8080/mltest/HelloWorld

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem too. Actually one of my program which was working already after few changes showed me this error. I even did undo to revert the changes, still It happened to me.
Finally I found a working solution for this for my scenario.

SIMPLE:

1.Just try to clean your project and run again. If it shows the same error and if you are sure there isn't any problem with your code then,

2.Enable the "Build Automatically" menu item under "Project" menu and try to clean your project. This time it worked for me.

Heard this is because when we make some changes and run, eclipse does some changes in its background too. So even if we revert the changes, eclipse might have not reverted the changes which it did in background. So performing these 2 steps will make sure it matches with the user change with its background change.

Hope it helps and solves your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem when I had the same exception with yours.

1. Ensure you add the right libraries, we need to add the Library Tomcat. At the beginning, I just added the servlet-api.jar, but someone told me it's not a right way. Maybe when you implemented the project in tomcat it had some Conflicts with Tomcat.
   [image]
2. Ensure your project in the right folder, `%Tomcat_HOME%\webapps\%projectName\WEB-INF\classes\.....`
3. Ensure web.xml in the right folder, and with right form,
   `%Tomcat_HOME%\webapps\%projectName\WEB-INF\web.xml`
4. Reload the application in Tomcat.
5. Access the servlet through URL:
   `http://localhost:port/%projectName%`

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid you made a mistake to try to access a servlet class directly.

Generally, the URL should be your any txt, jsp, html files under your application folder , but the servlet is used for response your "POST" or "Get" request from client side, it's immpossible to access it directly through URL.

Comment: Sorry, but this is complete nonsense. Servlets can perfectly be executed individually. You're likely confusing with the fact that entering an URL in browser address bar by default fires a HTTP GET request and that your servlets are missing a `doGet()` method.